# How do I get my ship to reach the Michelangelo?

Tags: nexus-the-jupiter-incident

Decided to fire up a game from my wall of shame: Nexus: the Jupiter Incident.

From a walkthrough:

> Eventually, the dispatcher from the Michelangelo will tell you to
>   approach the designated navigation point, and suddenly the "Approach"
>   button on the command  panel will no longer be greyed out. Select the
>   Stiletto by clicking on it, and  then right-click NAV MICHELANGELO in
>   the NPC Fleet list to move toward it. When you reach it, you'll get a
>   message confirming the completion of the  action and a cutscene will
>   begin. The Sunflower's fighters will contact you so  that they can
>   also tell you that the Sunflower's minefield is active.

OK, so I click on the station, then right click on it to get my ship moving toward it. Ship starts moving. Several minutes later I get a message about the minefield being active. Ship is still moving. Several minutes later, ship is still moving. Tried navigating to something else, that worked fine. But if I try to navigate to the station again it just circles and circles.

It won't reach the nav point.

edit: I right-clicked on the station, confirmed ship was moving and set a timer for 5 minutes. When the timer elapsed, the ship was still moving. This has to be a bug.